# Auth0 (auth0.com) + laravel. See site as other user see it. Or login as

Tags: php, laravel, auth0

I'm using auth0 as auth solution. I have is_admin column in users table.
So, I need to view site as some specific user see it. 
All I've found is like

```
Auth::login($user);
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
Auth::once($credentials);
```

But all this isn't works. Maybe there is some way to use auth0 as auth for users and standart laravel sessions as additional auth for needs like this?

Some docs:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/laravel/01-authorization
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/01-login

Comment: In which file you wrote this code `Auth::login($user);` ?

Comment: @C2486 it seems, that bascily auth::login($user); expects instanse of User class, but for Auth0 I need a Auth0User instance or smth like that. 

Do you have any idea of how to deal with that?